# Failed to mmap. No data written. Python Project.

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015

I started having troubles on running IronPython project (*.pyproj) from Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. Earlier everything was fine, but now my Visual Studio is working very-very slow. There is strange message in Output window:

```
Failed to mmap. No data written: Not enough storage is available to process this command.
```

It looks like this:[image]

Can anyone suggest why this strange message started to appear? As I said before, earlier everything worked fine and now my Visual Studio is super slow and then stops respond to my commands. I recreated 'ComponentModelCache' folder and even restarted my PC. Nothing helped. Can anyone provide me with some help?